# Refactor ConvertorToString class

Tags: java, strings, converting

Help me refactor this class that helps to represent an object state as String:

```
public class ConvertorToString {
    private static final String SEPARATOR_BETWEEN_FIELD_NAME_AND_VALUE = "=";
    private static final String SEPARATOR_BETWEEN_FIELDS = ", ";
    private static final String OPEN_FIELDS = "( ";
    private static final String CLOSE_FIELDS = " )";

    private final String className;
    private String[] fieldNames;
    private Object[] fieldValues;

    public static ConvertorToString buildFor(Object someObject) {
        return new ConvertorToString(someObject.getClass().getName());
    }

    private ConvertorToString(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public ConvertorToString withFieldNames(String... fieldNames) {
        this.fieldNames = fieldNames;
        return this;
    }

    public ConvertorToString withFieldValues(Object... fields) {
        this.fieldValues = fields;
        return this;
    }

    private class Field {
        private final int index;

        public Field(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public String toString() {
            checkIndex(index);
            return fieldNames[index] + SEPARATOR_BETWEEN_FIELD_NAME_AND_VALUE + fieldValues[index];
        }

        private void checkIndex(int index) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= countOfFields()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index should be inside a range: " +
                        "[0," + countOfFields() + "];  " + "but index was: " + index);
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        checkState();
        return className
               + OPEN_FIELDS +
                StringsCombiner.combine(getFields(), SEPARATOR_BETWEEN_FIELDS)
               + CLOSE_FIELDS;
    }

    private void checkState() {
        if (fieldNames == null || fieldValues == null || fieldNames.length != fieldValues.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("count of fieldNames should be equal to count of fieldValues");
        }
    }

    private List<Field> getFields() {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>(countOfFields());
        int countOfFields = countOfFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < countOfFields; ++i) {
            fields.add(new Field(i));
        }
        return fields;
    }

    private int countOfFields() {
        return fieldNames.length;
    }
}
```

**Using:**

```
class SomeClass {
    int id;
    String title;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ConvertorToString.buildFor(this)
            .withFieldNames("id", "title")
            .withFieldValues(id, title)
            .toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why your're using your own `toString()` instead of, for example, Guava's String Helper: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#toString?

Comment: @ElServidor I didn't know about the Guava's String Helper. Thanks for the link.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the idea of this utility class, but there are a few points I would like to mention.

Let's start with naming. I would rename the `ConvertorToString` class, probably, to one of the following `ToStringUtil`, `ToStringHelper`, `ObjectToString` or `ObjectToStringConvertor`. The rule of thumb is to put the `-or`/`-er` nouns in the end of the class name. Personally, I like the first two. Then come the constant fields which could be shorter. For instance, they could be named as `FIELD_NAME_AND_VALUE_SEPARATOR` instead of `SEPARATOR_BETWEEN_FIELD_NAME_AND_VALUE` and `FIELDS_SEPARATOR` instead of `SEPARATOR_BETWEEN_FIELDS`. That is, the 'BETWEEN' part is redundant because it's already obvious that a separator separates the one from the other. Two other fields would be better named as `FIELDS_START` and `FIELDS_END`, which is more intuitive.

Another thing is that you have two separate methods for adding the field names and values and then you check that there is a corresponding value for each field name in the `ConvertorToString.checkState()` method. You also check for indexes and arrays' length in the `ConvertorToString.Field.checkIndex()` method. All these checks are error-prone, but they could be eliminated by enforcing the one-to-one correspondence rule of the field names and values in a single method for adding those fields and their values:

```
ToStringUtil.addField(String name, Object value);
ToStringUtil.addFields(Map<String, Object> fields);
```

This way you control the state of your object and have no need in the `ConvertorToString.checkState()` and `ConvertorToString.Field.checkIndex()` methods anymore. Moreover, internally I would store the field names and values in one data structure, rather than in two separate arrays. The single structure could be a `Map<String, Object>` or a `List<Field>`, the latter one is preferable if you have a `Field` class. This brings us to the `ConvertorToString.Field` class.

I think, it would be more practical to encapsulate the field names and values within the `ConvertorToString.Field` class, which will yield a better OOP-style design. Also, this change will allow you to transform the `ConvertorToString.Field` class from an inner class to a static nested class, because you don't need the reference to the outer class anymore. After you encapsulate the field name and its value in the `ConvertorToString.Field` class, the `FIELD_NAME_AND_VALUE_SEPARATOR` field would naturally belong to the `ConvertorToString.Field` class. And because the class name is `Field`, the `FIELD_NAME_AND_VALUE_SEPARATOR` field could further be renamed to `NAME_AND_VALUE_SEPARATOR`.

One other opinion on the `ConvertorToString` constants would be that you don't actually need them because you don't use them anywhere else besides the `toString()` methods. So, you could just use the string literals instead:

```
public class ToStringConvertor {
    private final String className;
    private final List<Field> fields;
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "%s(%s)", 
            className, 
            StringsCombiner.combine(fields, ", ")
        );
    }

    private static class Field {
        private final String name;
        private final Object value;
        ...
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s=%s", name, value);
        }
    }
}
```